# Why is my TestNG xml file not targeting my Java Class?

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

Why is my TestNG xml file not targeting my Runner Class?

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Cucumber Framework" verbose="2">
    <test name="Cucumber Tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.MainRunner"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

location of the runner class:

CucumberFramework\src\test\java\CucumberFramework\runners
CucumberFramework\src\test\java\CucumberFramework\runners\MainRunner.java

Please note: if i execute the runner class directly, everything works accordingly, it seems the xml file is unable to locate the runner class, any ideas?

**Runner class code:**

```
package CucumberFramework.runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions (
        features = {"src/test/java/CucumberFramework/featureFiles/"},
        glue = {"CucumberFramework.steps"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber","json:target/cucumber.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
        )

public class MainRunner {
}
```

Comment: Is runners.MainRunner contain @Test annotation?

Comment: Add the code for the Runner class...

Comment: @murali selenium thanks now added runner class code

Comment: @Grasshopper added the runner class code, thanks

Comment: You are calling a junit runner from testng, it will never work. You should look at using TestNG-cucumber runner instead...

Comment: http://sahajamit.github.io/Cucumber-JVM-with-TestNG/

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the junit classes with testng xml file by define the property junit="true" as given below

```
<suite name="Cucumber Framework" >
   <test name="Cucumber Tests" junit="true">
      <classes>
         <class name="CucumberFramework.runners.MainRunner" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```